# ConfigurationManager.Connectionstrings("DBConnection") - Null Exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, connection-string, app-config

In data layer I am trying to fetch connection string from app.config.

App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****; Password=***" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Fetching Value:

```
Shared _ConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnection").ConnectionString
```

this is not working.

And I tried

```
Shared _ConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(0).ConnectionString
```

it is partially fetching - "Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=True"

Kindly explain.

Answer (score -3):

Try using `ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString` instead of `ConnectionStrings("DBConnection").ConnectionString`.

Comment: in VB.net not possible!